# Running ruby project with systemd service cannot find gemfile

Tags: ruby, bundler, systemd

I would like to run a ruby project that uses bundle as a systemd service.

The project is: https://github.com/jcs/bitwarden-ruby/

I installed ruby and bundler by running `sudo apt-get install ruby-full` and `sudo gem install bundler`

In the project directory I run `bundle install --deployment`.

In my systemd service I have:

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/env RACK_ENV=production ALLOW_SIGNUPS=1 /usr/local/bin/bundle exec rackup -p 4567 /var/lib/bitwarden/bitwarden-ruby/config.ru`

Runnning this command in the terminal does work.

However when I start the service I get an error:

`bash[7924]: Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`

The bundle directory is at `/var/lib/bitwarden/bitwarden-ruby/.bundle`.
Why can it not find it? Thanks!

Comment: That is answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200654/executing-chdir-before-starting-systemd-service

Comment: Put this `WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/bitwarden/bitwarden-ruby` into your systemd service file.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk thanks this was the problem.